# Limiting asynchronous calls in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I've got a Node.js app that gets a list of file locally and uploads them to a server. This list could contain thousands of files.

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   upload_file(files[i]);
}
```

If I execute this with thousands of files, upload_file will get called thousands of times all at once, and most likely die (or at least struggle). In the synchronous world, we'd create a thread pool and limit it to a certain number of threads. Is there a simple way to limit how many asynchronous calls get executed at once?

Comment: A similar but rate limit (per sec/minute) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253425/throttle-and-queue-up-api-requests-due-to-per-second-cap

Comment: The fact that this is even a problem is why I don't like Node.js

Answer (score 77):

As usual, I recommend Caolan McMahon's [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Make your `upload_file` function take a callback as it's second parameter:

```
var async = require("async");

function upload_file(file, callback) {
    // Do funky stuff with file
    callback();
}

var queue = async.queue(upload_file, 10); // Run ten simultaneous uploads

queue.drain = function() {
    console.log("All files are uploaded");
};

// Queue your files for upload
queue.push(files);

queue.concurrency = 20; // Increase to twenty simultaneous uploads
```

Comment: My function never returns.  I got the "All files are uploaded" message, but my process doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 26):

The answer above, re: [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) on NPM is the best answer, but if you'd like to learn more about control flow:

---

You should look into control flow patterns. There's a wonderful discussion on control flow patterns in [Chapter 7 of Mixu's Node Book](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html). Namely, I'd look at the example in 7.2.3: *Limited parallel - an asynchronous, parallel, concurrency limited for loop*.

I've adapted his example:

```
function doUpload() {
    // perform file read & upload here...
}

var files   = [...];
var limit   = 10;       // concurrent read / upload limit
var running = 0;        // number of running async file operations

function uploader() {
    while(running < limit && files.length > 0) {
        var file = files.shift();
        doUpload(file, function() {
            running--;
            if(files.length > 0)
                uploader();
        });
        running++;
    }
}

uploader();
```

Comment: It works fine and runs only the specified number of async operations; however I noticed that the value of `file` inside `doUpload` (e.g. before `running--;`) doesn't contain the expected value, for example `console.log(file)` will print the same file 10 times on the first 10 lines (if `limit` has a value of 10, that is)

Answer (score 8):

You should try queueing. I assume that a callback is fired when `upload_file()` finishes. Something like this should do the trick (untested):

```
function upload_files(files, maxSimultaneousUploads, callback) {
    var runningUploads = 0,
        startedUploads = 0,
        finishedUploads = 0;

    function next() {
        runningUploads--;
        finishedUploads++;

        if (finishedUploads == files.length) {
            callback();
        } else {
            // Make sure that we are running at the maximum capacity.
            queue();
        }
    }

    function queue() {
        // Run as many uploads as possible while not exceeding the given limit.
        while (startedUploads < files.length && runningUploads < maxSimultaneousUploads) {
            runningUploads++;
            upload_file(files[startedUploads++], next);
        }
    }

    // Start the upload!
    queue();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The others answers seem to be outdated. This can be solved easily using [paralleLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) from [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). Below is how to use it. I haven't tested it.

```
var tasks = files.map(function(f) {
    return function(callback) {
        upload_file(f, callback)
    }
});

parallelLimit(tasks, 10, function(){
});
```

Comment: is there any difference between the queue function and the parallellimit?

Answer (score 0):

**No external libraries. Just plain JS.**

It can be resolved using recursion.

The idea is that initially we immediately start the maximum allowed number of uploads and each of these requests should recursively initiate a new upload on its completion.

In this example I populate successful responses together with errors and I execute all requests but it's possible to slightly modify algorithm if you want to terminate batch upload on the first failure.

```js
async function batchUpload(files, limit) {
  limit = Math.min(files.length, limit);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const responsesOrErrors = new Array(files.length);
    let startedCount = 0;
    let finishedCount = 0;
    let hasErrors = false;

    function recursiveUpload() {
      let index = startedCount++;

      uploadFile(files[index])
        .then(res => {
          responsesOrErrors[index] = res;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          responsesOrErrors[index] = error;
          hasErrors = true;
        })
        .finally(() => {
          finishedCount++;
          if (finishedCount === files.length) {
            hasErrors ? reject(responsesOrErrors) : resolve(responsesOrErrors);
          } else if (startedCount < files.length) {
            recursiveUpload();
          }
        });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      recursiveUpload();
    }
  });
}

async function uploadFile(file) {
  console.log(`${file} started`);
  const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (delay <= 1000) {
        console.log(`${file} finished successfully`);
        resolve(`${file} success`);
      } else {
        console.log(`${file} finished with error`);
        reject(`${file} error`);
      }
    }, delay);
  });
}

const files = new Array(10).fill('file').map((file, index) => `${file}_${index + 1}`);

batchUpload(files, 3)
  .then(responses => console.log('All successfull', responses))
  .catch(responsesWithErrors => console.log('All with several failed', responsesWithErrors));
```