# Timed promise queue / throttle

Tags: javascript, queue, promise, bluebird, rate-limiting

I have a [request-promise](https://github.com/tyabonil/request-promise) function that makes a request to an API. I'm rate-limited by this API and I keep getting the error message:

```
Exceeded 2 calls per second for api client. Reduce request rates to resume uninterrupted service.
```

I'm running a couple of [`Promise.each`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#eachfunction-iterator---promise) loops in parallel which is causing the issue, if I run just one instance of [`Promise.each`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#eachfunction-iterator---promise) everything runs fine. Within these [`Promise.each`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#eachfunction-iterator---promise) calls they lead to the same function a with a [request-promise](https://github.com/tyabonil/request-promise) call. I want to wrap this function with another `queue` function and set the interval to `500` milliseconds so that a `request` isn't made after one another, or parallel, but set to that time, on queue.  The thing is I still need these promises to get their contents even if it takes a rather long time to get a response.

Is there anything that will do this for me? Something I can wrap a function in and it will respond at a set interval and not in parallel or fire functions one after another?

*Update:* Perhaps it does need to be promise specific, I tried to use underscore's throttle function

```
var debug = require("debug")("throttle")
var _ = require("underscore")
var request = require("request-promise")

function requestSite(){
  debug("request started")
  function throttleRequest(){
    return request({
      "url": "https://www.google.com"
    }).then(function(response){
      debug("request finished")
    })
  }
  return _.throttle(throttleRequest, 100)
}

requestSite()
requestSite()
requestSite()
```

And all I got back was this:

```
$ DEBUG=* node throttle.js 
throttle request started +0ms
throttle request started +2ms
throttle request started +0ms
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your actual code so we have something to work with?

Comment: @jfriend00 My implementation is pretty specific to an API. What I have is a wrapper for `request` that a whole bunch of functions use. That's the point I can throttle at. I want to wrap that wrapper containing `request` with some kind of queueing function.

Comment: Generic solution to this sort of problems: [spex](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update

The last answer was wrong, this works but I still think I can do better:

```
// call fn at most count times per delay.
const debounce = function (fn, delay, count) {
    let working = 0, queue = [];
    function work() {
        if ((queue.length === 0) || (working === count)) return;
        working++;
        Promise.delay(delay).tap(() => working--).then(work);
        let {context, args, resolve} = queue.shift();
        resolve(fn.apply(context, args));
    }
    return function debounced() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            queue.push({context: this, args: arguments, resolve});
            if (working < count) work();
        });
    };
};

function mockRequest() {
    console.log("making request");
    return Promise.delay(Math.random() * 100);
}

var bounced = debounce(mockRequest, 800, 5);
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) bounced();
setTimeout(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) bounced();
},2000);
```

---

So you need to make the requests throttle function-wide - that's fine. Promises have queueing pretty much built in.

```
var p = Promise.resolve(); // our queue

function makeRequest(){
    p = p.then(function(){ // queue the promise, wait for the queue
        return request("http://www.google.com");
    });
    var p2 = p; // get a local reference to the promise
    // add 1000 ms delay to queue so the next caller has to wait 
    p = p.delay(1000); 
    return p2;
};
```

Now makeRequest calls will be at least 1000ms apart.

jfriend has pointed out that you need two requests per second and not a single one - this is just as easily solvable with a second queue:

```
var p = Promise.resolve(1); // our first queue
var p2 = Promise.resolve(2); // our second queue

function makeRequest(){

    var turn = Promise.any([p, p2]).then(function(val){ 

        // add 1000 ms delay to queue so the next caller has to wait 
        // here we wait for the request too although that's not really needed, 
        // check both options out and decide which works better in your case
        if(val === 1){
            p = p.return(turn).delay(1, 1000);
        } else {
            p2 = p2.return(turn).delay(1, 1000); 
        }
        return request("http://www.google.com");
    });

    return turn; // return the actual promise
};
```

This can be generalized to `n` promises using an array similarly

Comment: An efficient 2 calls/sec is a bit more involved than this.  For example, you should be able to send 2 calls immediately, but then have to wait a second for the third one that comes in if it comes right away, but not wait at all, if it comes one second later.

Comment: @ThomasReggi it depends on how important speed is - I've added a second solution that actually does "2 requests per second" although the first one is simpler.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've updated the answer - thanks for noticing again.

Comment: `p = p.then(function(){ return Promise.delay(1000); }); ` can be written as `p = p.delay(1000)`, `p = p.then(function() {return turn})` can be written as `p = p.return(turn)` and so on.. jesus man learn the api :d

Comment: The second one doesn't look right, `queueId` is always `undefined` and you are waiting 1 second in addition to whatever time it took to process the request

Comment: I actually cannot get this to work no matter what, I guess it's better to implement standard algorithms. Btw, the delay instance method only takes a time and passes through the previous fulfillment value instead of taking custom value. So `.delay(1000).return(1)`

Comment: Now if only I had a library author here to allow the syntax.. :p

Comment: Oh, I get it, since it's `any`ing the promises before the inner part assigns them, that shouldn't be too hard to fix.

Comment: Is this production ready? Does this solution work (so far)? It gets the job done but it's not accurate to the application? Not exactly sure of the problem @Esailija is describing.

Comment: I'm using one of the old versions, not debounced one. It would be helpful to have some version history here.

Comment: There is revision history in every question in SO. You should probably use he newer one which is more correct. You can use it in production it works - just make sure you understand it first - also I think it can be prettier

Comment: This is fine if "2 calls per second" genuinely means "2 calls, however close to each other, in any given second". If however it really means "1 call in any given 500ms period" then, with fast enough server responses, the any-p-p2 solution could still provoke the "Exceeded ..." error.

Comment: Forgot about the version history!! @Roamer-1888 yeah I'll have to do some testing to see hoe specific the server is.

Comment: Sorry, I was goggle-eyed by the time I got to the version history. IMHO top-posting is confusing here (unlike email). The "debounce" solution is hard to follow but I think my "if however ... could still provoke" observation applies equally to it.

Comment: Hate to keep this going, but I'm getting an error https://gist.github.com/reggi/88027e0ffd6f2ef31650

Comment: If you are interested, have an alternative answer.

Comment: @ThomasReggi `debounced` returns a _function_ that returns a promise, not a promise itself, if you want to invoke it you'll have to call `debounced()().then` and not `debounced().then` since you might want to have several differently debounced functions. Check the example usage at the end of the answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The problem with the latest updated solution is that I'm trying to pass an arg to `mockRequest`. In your example request is more of a set thing and the `bounce` is more of a factory for calling the same thing. With `mockRequest` as a func with parameters it changes that. There's more here, https://gist.github.com/reggi/71ffe22aa41c1ec08773, would love your help!!!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I created a new issue here for my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459812/way-to-provide-this-to-the-global-scope