# Way to provide "this" to the global scope?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, promise, bluebird

I'm working with a `debounce` function found [here in this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27563358/340688). It's a promise that allows for throttling requests.

The debounce function won't work for some reason when it's nested within a function because the `setTimeout` calls to the request seem to get sent all at once. It needs to be referenced directly I think.

I can't do something like this because it needs to be referenced directly

```
function bounced(item){
  return debounce(mockRequest, 800, 5)(item)
}
```

This is how it should be used

```
var bounced = debounce(mockRequest, 800, 5)
```

The problem is I'm creating an API object like this and neither options will work

```
API.prototype.request = function(options){
  return this.debounce(this.makeRequest, 1000, 2)(options)
}

API.prototype.request = this.debounce(this.makeRequest, 1000, 2) // duh
```

I'm looking for some way to use `this` and not call the debounce method directly.

Ideally something like this would be nice

```
API.prototype.request = function(){
  return this.debounce(this.makeRequest, 1000, 2)
}()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

```
API.prototype.request = API.prototype.debounce(API.prototype.makeRequest, 1000, 2)
```

You have neither an instance (`this`) nor an `options` object at the time of creating the method. Those are supplied to the `debounced` function, where they are stored and then (possibly later) used to call the supplied function.

Btw, it probably makes no sense to place `debounce` on the prototype of your API - it's a generic helper method, not an instance method. Also notice that when you `debounce()` the prototype method, *all* of your calls will be *globally* debounced. If you want to have one queue per instance of your API, you should better do

```
function API() {
    // in the constructor:
    this.request = Helpers.debounce(this.makeRequest);
}
API.prototype.makeRequest = function() { … };
// no prototype .request() method
```

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't realize that each function would independently retain their states.

Comment: Thanks for the second example, I've updated my code to reflect that! Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasReggi I saw you pinged me about this on the other answer - I'd just like to verify that this solution is correct. It's definitely how I intended it to be used. \

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: That feels like a double checkmark :-)