# Throttle / Debounce number of calls per second

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, throttling

I'm working with an API that only allows you to make 200 calls per second (1000ms) using a promise request library like `request-promise` or `axios` how can you debounce / throttle the requests that are made to a URL / server using rx.js? I noticed a [throttle method](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md) in the rx documentation, but it won't calculate calls per second.

This is a function that wraps a promise and will queue them to account for a API-rate limit. I'm looking for similar functionality with Rx.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459812/way-to-provide-this-to-the-global-scope#28459875
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561158/timed-promise-queue-throttle

module.exports = promiseDebounce

function promiseDebounce(fn, delay, count) {
  var working = 0, queue = [];
  function work() {
    if ((queue.length === 0) || (working === count)) return;
    working++;
    Promise.delay(delay).tap(function () { working--; }).then(work);
    var next = queue.shift();
    next[2](fn.apply(next[0], next[1]));
  }
  return function debounced() {
    var args = arguments;
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      queue.push([this, args, resolve]);
      if (working < count) work();
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include what you have already tried ;)

Comment: Hey @bytec0de valid. I'm just curious if a library / method already exists, or this problem has been solved, or if there's something I've overlooked. I don't have any code, and I'm not expecting any code.

Comment: It's very simple to use debouncing. Here's a nice post: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: The problem with debouncing, is you lose the requests that get dropped from debounce.

Comment: @Surim I updated the post above with a function for promises that does what I'm looking for. Perhaps `throttle` / `debounce` aren't the correct terminology but I'm definitely not looking to drop requests. More like control how often they flow through a stream, perhaps `valve` would be a better term, if this doesn't already exist.

Comment: @ThomasReggi in that case, just use `setInterval` and add all of your calls to an array. Every X seconds, `shift` the next call in the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had a similar issue the other day for rate limiting access to a resource. I came across this repo [bahmutov/node-rx-cycle](https://github.com/bahmutov/node-rx-cycle/blob/master/src/rate-limit.js). Here is the example in a [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JperyY?p=preview) I put together to demonstrate this. It takes input from a text input field and prepends it to a `<ul>`. Each `<li>` is only prepended every 1000ms, and any others are queued.

```
// Impure
const textInput = document.querySelector('.example-input');
const prependToOutput = function(item) {
  const ul = document.querySelector('.example-output');
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
  ul.insertBefore(li, ul.firstChild);
};

// Pure
const eventTargetValue = function(ele) { return ele.target.value; };
const textInputKeyUpStream = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(textInput, 'keyup')
  .map(eventTargetValue);

// Stream
rateLimit(textInputKeyUpStream, 1000)
  .timeInterval()
  .map(function(ti) { return ti.value + ' (' + ti.interval + 'ms)'; })
  .subscribe(prependToOutput);
```

Hope this helps.