# resolving Promises sequentially

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

**EDIT:** This is for an Electron project, with a local server spun up on the user's system. So, any concerns about what happens if multiple users attempt simultaneous access can be ignored!

---

My client code is generating an array of JavaScript objects, which I'm calling *packets*. There can be potentially infinite *packets*, although between 1 and 10 is the most common use-case.

I need to make API calls to a backend route, one per *packet*, passing a *packet* as an argument to each call.

However, the backend does some **heavy** computational work on each *packet*, to the point where attempting to crunch more than 2-3 packets at once crashes the server.

Is it possible to resolve *Promises* synchronously, such that the second *Promise* only fires when the first resolves, the third firing after the second, and so on?

It's my understanding that *Promise.all()* makes all calls simultaneously, which doesn't help me here.

(I also know that this is an anti-pattern, but for my specific set of requirements, I'm not sure what else to do)

I know this is purely abstract, but any thoughts would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Yeah 'sequentially' would've been better semantics.
I just meant that Promise 1 needs to finish before Promise 2 starts, Promise 2 needs to finish before Promise 3 starts and so on, up until Promise N.

Comment: `My client code is generating an array of JavaScript objects` - let me ask this. Are you creating the array, and once the array is generated, then you make the API calls? Or is it more of a situation where these objects are created on the fly and you want to ensure you only call the API one at a time - i.e. the "queue" answer below would be ideal

Comment: Sounds like you're just describing [chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining). Use [composition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Composition).

Comment: One option is to think of this as a [Promise-throttling problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38385419/1426891) where `n = 1`, though it sounds like you'd be comfortable with `n = 2` or `n = 3` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Get weird with Promises

An async queue, a spin-off one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701209/node-js-working-with-an-api-limit-of-5-requests-per-second/46701466#46701466); I've added random completion time to simulate a real environment:

```js
class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this.queue = [];
    }

    enqueue(obj) {
        return this.queue.push(obj);
    }

    dequeue() {
        return this.queue.shift();
    }

    hasWork() {
        return (this.queue.length > 0);
    }
}

class AsyncQueue extends Queue {
    constructor(job) {
        super();
        this.job = job;
    }

    process(cb) {
        return this.job(this.dequeue()).then(data => {
            cb(data);
            if (this.hasWork())
                return this.process(cb);
        });
    }
}

//MUST RETURN Promise
function work() {
    var duration = chooseDelay();
    console.log('START JOB, I.E., MAKE REQUEST (will take %s)', duration);
    return t_o(duration);
}

function report() {
    console.log('JOB DONE');
}

function done() {
    console.log('ALL WORK DONE');
}

function t_o(delay) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve();
        }, delay);
    });
}

function chooseDelay() {
    var delays = [200, 1000, 4000, 100, 50, 7000];
    return delays[parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % delays.length];
}

var q = new AsyncQueue(work);

for (var packet = 0; packet < 10; ++packet)
    q.enqueue(packet);

q.process(report).then(done);
```

Comment: This is really nice. Great use of classes and helper functions, very clear. You could work around not returning a promise by wrapping the `this.job()` call with `Promise.resolve()`, but maybe this is not something you want to silently allow, because it likely indicates a bug like forgetting to return the promise, for instance.

Comment: Is there any access to the results of *each* call?

Comment: sure, `report` has a `data` param

Comment: To clarify, process() calls `cb` param with `data` arg.

Comment: oh, right, your example function `t_o` resolves undefined :p

Comment: This worked great! I put together a quick example to test it, and had no issues!
However, a colleague pointed out that we are using Bluebird.js to handle our Promises, and they have several functions for doing just this sort of thing (specifically `reduce()`, `each()` and `reflect()`), so that's what I actually ended up going with.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to an otherwise good answer, here's a really simple queue that works (`work` function shamelessly copied and expanded from other answer)

```js
    // Here is the queue "creator"
    let promiseQueue = fn => {
        let q = Promise.resolve();
        return (...args) => q = q.then(() => fn(...args));
    };
    // that's it, that's the whole code for a promise queue

    // here we create a queue
    var q = promiseQueue(work);

    // simple mock asynchronous function
    function work({index, data}) {
        var duration = parseInt(Math.random() * 100) + 100;
        console.log('START JOB %s, I.E., MAKE REQUEST (will take %s) and should result with %s', index, duration, (index +1) * data);
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration)) // mock a delay
        .then(() => ({index, result:(index + 1) * data})); // and some "processing"
    }


    // simulating two "chunks" of packets, generated a millisecond apart, but still, the sequence will be maintained
    setTimeout(() => {
        var packets = Array.from({length:10}, (_, index) => ({index, data:parseInt(Math.random() * 10000)}));
        var promises = packets.map(packet => q(packet));
        // the results in promise all are all the results of this batch of "packets"
        Promise.all(promises).then(results => console.log(results));
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(() => {
        var packets = Array.from({length:10}, (_, index) => ({index: index + 10, data:parseInt(Math.random() * 10000)}));
        var promises = packets.map(packet => q(packet));
        Promise.all(promises).then(results => console.log(results));
    }, 101);
```

Answer (score 1):

the simple function to execute promises sequentially

```
const sequentiallyExecuting = (promises) => {
    let promise = Promise.resolve();
    promises.forEach((task) => {
        promise = promise.then((data) => {
            return task;
        })
    });

    return promise;
}
// pass array of promises to this function
sequentiallyExecuting(promises).then((data) =>{
   console.log("all requests completed sequentially");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
'use strict';

// job to be done
function job(params) {
 return function () {
  console.log('job started', params);
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
   setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('job finished');
    resolve();
   }, 1000);
  })
 }
}

// data to be processed sequentially 
var params = [
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5
];
// reduce data to Promise sequence
params.reduce(function (cum, cur) {
 return cum.then(job(cur));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 0):

With async/await it becomes trivial:

```
while (promiseArray.length > 0)
        await promiseArray.shift();
```