# Limit Q promise concurrency in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, q

Is there any way to limit the number of concurrent Q promises to be executed at once in node js?

I am building a web **scraper** , which must request and parse more 3000+ pages and without throttle some of the requests i make aren't responded to on time, so the connection rests and the needed response (html code) becomes unavailable.

To counter act this, i found that limiting the number of requests my problem goes away.

---

I have tried the following methods but to no avail:

- [Concurrency limit in Q promises - node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366434/concurrency-limit-in-q-promises-node)
- [How can I limit Q promise concurrency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546373/how-can-i-limit-q-promise-concurrency)
- https://gist.github.com/gaearon/7930162
- https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/throat

I need to request an array of urls, doing only 1 request at a time and when all urls in the array have completed, then return the results in a array.

```
function processWebsite() {
  //computed by this stage
  urls = [u1,u2,u3,u4,l5,u6,u7,u8,u9];

  var promises = throttle(urls,1,myfunction);

  // myfunction returns a Q promise and takes a considerable 
  // amount of time to resolve (approximately 2-5 minutes)
  
  Q.all(promises).then(function(results){
      //work with the results of the promises array
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request a new url in a `then()` block

```
myFunction(urls[0]).then(function(result) {
  myFunction(urls[1]).then(function(result) {
    myFunction(urls[2]).then(function(result) {
      ...
    });
  });
});
```

Of course, this would be its dynamic behaviour. I'd mantain a queue and dequeue a single url once a promise is resolved. Then make another request. And perhaps have a hash object relating urls to results.

A second take:

```
var urls = ...;
var limit = ...;
var dequeue = function() {
  return an array containing up to limit
};

var myFunction = function(dequeue) {
  var urls = dequeue();

  $q.all(process urls);
};

myFunction(dequeue).then(function(result) {
  myFunction(dequeue).then(function(result) {
    myFunction(dequeue).then(function(result) {
      ...
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I thought of something similar, but this seems to defeat the purpose of promises, it has a very similar structure to standard callbacks in JavaScript. Also I can not easily specify a maximum currency greater than 1 with this style of code. Is there no throttle Q-promise type solution?

Comment: i think a general version is attainabled. I edit my response. A throttle Q-promise would work this way, I think.

Comment: It's answers like this that make me resort to wrapping in callbacks and just using async.js - surely there is a better way than this with Q?! (no offence to Werlang for how he worded his answer, just the nature of the solution itself)

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this, which will iterate over each URL, building a chain of promises that run when the previous one finishes, and resolves with an array of the request results.

```
return urls.reduce(function(acc, url){
    return acc.then(function(results)
        return myfunction(url).then(function(requestResult){
             return results.concat(requestResult)
        });
    });
}, Q.resolve([]));
```

You could turn that into a helper too:

```
var results = map(urls, myfunction);

function map(items, fn){
    return items.reduce(function(acc, item){
        return acc.then(function(results)
            return fn(item).then(function(result){
                 return results.concat(result)
            });
        });
    }, Q.resolve([])
}
```

Note, the [`bluebird`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#option-concurrency) promise library has a helper to simplify this kind of thing.

```
return Bluebird.map(urls, myfunction, {concurrency: 1});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the link to the promise library, thing is, the project uses q promises and at the moment it is too big to change the promise library, but ill use this for future projects ;)

Comment: Yup, that's why I gave options for both :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is my stab at making a throttled `map` function for Q.

```
function qMap(items, worker, concurrent) {
    var result = Q.defer();
    var work = [];
    var working = 0;
    var done = 0;

    concurrent = parseInt(concurrent, 10) || 1;

    function getNextIndex() {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (typeof work[i] === "undefined") return i;
        }
    }
    function doneWorking() {
        working--;
        done++;
        result.notify( +((100 * done / items.length).toFixed(1)) );
        if (!startWorking() && done === items.length) {
            result.resolve(work);
        }
    }
    function startWorking() {
        var index = getNextIndex();
        if (typeof index !== "undefined" && working < concurrent) {
            working++;
            work[index] = worker(items[index]).finally(doneWorking);
            return true;
        }
    }
    while (startWorking());
    return result.promise;
}
```

It accepts

- an array of `items` to work on (URLs, in your case),
- a `worker` (which must be a function that accepts an item and returns a promise)
- and a maximum value of `concurrent` items to work on at any given time.

It returns

- a promise and
- resolves to an array of settled promises when all workers have finished.

It does not fail, you must inspect the individual promises to determine the overall state of the operation.

In your case you would use it like that, for example with 15 concurrent requests:

```
// myfunction returns a Q promise and takes a considerable 
// amount of time to resolve (approximately 2-5 minutes)

qMap(urls, myfunction, 15)
.progress(function (percentDone) {
    console.log("progress: " + percentDone);
})
.done(function (urlPromises) {
    console.log("all done: " + urlPromises);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**No external libraries. Just plain JS.**

If you really need just **1 single request at a time** then it's easy using async/await:

```js
async function processWebsite(urls) {
  const responsesAndErrors = new Array(urls.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    try {
      responsesAndErrors[i] = await processPage(urls[i]);
    } catch(error) {
      responsesAndErrors[i] = error;
    }
  }
  return responsesAndErrors;
}

async function processPage(url) {
  console.log(`${url} started`);
  const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (delay <= 1000) {
        console.log(`${url} finished successfully`);
        resolve(`${url} success`);
      } else {
        console.log(`${url} finished with error`);
        reject(`${url} error`);
      }
    }, delay);
  });
}

const urls = new Array(10).fill('url').map((url, index) => `${url}_${index + 1}`);

processWebsite(urls).then(responses => console.log('All', responses));
```

If you need **more than 1 request at a time** then it can be resolved using recursion.

The idea is that initially we immediately fetch the maximum allowed number of pages and each of these requests should recursively initiate a new request on its completion.

In this example I populate successful responses together with errors and I process all pages but it's possible to slightly modify algorithm if you want to terminate batch processing on the first failure.

```js
async function processWebsite(urls, limit) {
  limit = Math.min(urls.length, limit);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const responsesOrErrors = new Array(urls.length);
    let startedCount = 0;
    let finishedCount = 0;
    let hasErrors = false;

    function recursiveProcess() {
      let index = startedCount++;

      processPage(urls[index])
        .then(res => {
          responsesOrErrors[index] = res;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          responsesOrErrors[index] = error;
          hasErrors = true;
        })
        .finally(() => {
          finishedCount++;
          if (finishedCount === urls.length) {
            hasErrors ? reject(responsesOrErrors) : resolve(responsesOrErrors);
          } else if (startedCount < urls.length) {
            recursiveProcess();
          }
        });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      recursiveProcess();
    }
  });
}

async function processPage(url) {
  console.log(`${url} started`);
  const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (delay <= 1000) {
        console.log(`${url} finished successfully`);
        resolve(`${url} success`);
      } else {
        console.log(`${url} finished with error`);
        reject(`${url} error`);
      }
    }, delay);
  });
}

const urls = new Array(10).fill('url').map((url, index) => `${url}_${index + 1}`);

processWebsite(urls, 3)
  .then(responses => console.log('All successfull', responses))
  .catch(responsesWithErrors => console.log('All with several failed', responsesWithErrors));
```