# Is it possible to limit async tasks in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have the following section of async code:

```js
async.forEach(list, function(file, loopCallback) {
    console.log("file");
    loopCallback();
}, {
    console.log("all done!");
});
```

It prints the name of all my files in my list, great. Now, I want to limit the amount of files I am processing in parallel. What if I only want to handle one file at a time?

I have heard of `async.ParallelLimit`, and `async.Queue`, and would like to know how to adapt this code to fit one of them, specifically `parallelLimit`.

Any ideas?

Comment: so... you know that async has options that do what you want, but you want us to convert your code to one of those other options..

Comment: You didn't even take a look at [the docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#documentation), did you? Just use `async.eachLimit`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting asynchronous calls in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539886/limiting-asynchronous-calls-in-node-js)

Answer (score 5):

I think what you need is [eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), not `parallelLimit`. Here is an example:

```
async.each(
    list,
    1, // limit
    function(file, callback) {
        console.log('Processing file ' + file);
        callback();
    },
    function(err){
        if( err ) {
          console.log('Failed to process');
        } else {
          console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! that was perfect!

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds you are supposed to upvote when someone provides a good answer :) At this point, I upvoted for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using (every) instead of foreach

```
var count = 0;
var totalcount = 5;
async.every(function() {
// Do something.
count++;
if (count == 5)
   return false;
   else return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `async.mapLimit` is what you need:

```
async.mapLimit([1,2,3,4,5], 3, function(value, loopCallback) {
    // will process by 3 items at time
    console.log(value);
    loopCallback(value);
}
```

It is mentioned in the `map` [description](https://github.com/caolan/async#map).